# Sibling of the second node with a specific value

Tags: xml, xpath

This is the example xml I'm working with:

```
<data>
 <menu>
     <date>2017-11-08</date>
     <type>S</type>
     <name>onion soup</name>
 </menu>

 <menu>
     <date>2017-11-08</date>
     <type>L</type>
     <name>ham sandwich</name>
 </menu>

 <menu>
     <date>2017-11-09</date>
     <type>S</type>
     <name>pumpkin soup</name>  
 </menu>

 <menu>
     <date>2017-11-09</date>
     <type>L</type>
     <name>cheese sandwich</name>
 </menu>

 <menu>
      <date>2017-11-10</date>
      <type>S</type>
      <name>sweet potato soup</name>
 </menu>

 <menu>
      <date>2017-11-10</date>
      <type>L</type>
      <name>chicken sandwich</name>
 </menu>
</data>
```

The xml is dynamically changing everyday so it always starts with current day menu.

I'm looking for a line that will always show 'tomorrow's soup', so today (8th) it's suppose to give me the value "pumpkin soup", 9th it will to show "sweet potato soup", 10th it will show the value of the new soup that will appear in the xml when it changes.

Is there a line that will show me the sibling of the second "type" with the value "S" in the xml feed?

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

I've tried this:

```
/data/menu/name[../type/text() = "S"] or /data/menu[type[text()='S']]/name
```

which is suppose to show all of them but in the software I'm working with it shows the first soup. But I have no idea how to show the second one.

Edit2:

```
(/data/menu[type='S'])[2]/following-sibling::menu[1]/name
```

thanks, but this actually gives me tomorrow's lunch name, not soup name

Edit3:

It actually led me to a solution, which may not be the most elegant way but I think it should do the trick (I had no idea I can use double brackets like this, so thanks!)

```
(/data/menu[type='S'])[2]/name
```

Comment: Show what you have tried already

Answer (score 0):

Name of next menu item after the second "type" with the value "S"

```
(/data/menu[type='S'])[2]/following-sibling::menu[1]/name
```